# Extract coordinates out of xml with xpath and some criterias

Tags: xml, xpath

i have spent hours of searching for a solution, but now i need your help. Probably you will joking about me, but...anyway.
I'd like to fetch the coordinates and maybe some othe information when xpath matches the crtiteria value=bnb

I tried the syntax //Data/value['bnb']/ancestor::Point/coordinates[text()] with no result.

```
      <Placemark xmlns="">
    <name><![CDATA[Malcesine]]></name>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>10.8103913069,45.7645853643</coordinates>
    </Point>
    <ExtendedData>
      <Data name="tournumber">
        <value>1</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="guidename">
        <value>Lake Garda</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="category">
        <value>numeration</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="category">
        <value>bnb</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="WayPointNumber">
        <value>3</value>
      </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark xmlns="">
    <name><![CDATA[Gelateria Cento per cento]]></name>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>10.8087927103,45.7659774682</coordinates>
    </Point>
    <ExtendedData>
      <Data name="tournumber">
        <value>1</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="guidename">
        <value>Lake Garda</value>
      </Data>
      <Data name="WayPointNumber">
        <value>3</value>
      </Data>
    </ExtendedData>
  </Placemark>
```

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to go back up the tree with `ancestor::`, put the predicate on `Placemark`...

```
//Placemark[ExtendedData/Data/value='bnb']/Point/coordinates
```

Most of the time it's easier to create a path directly to the element and then add the predicates to filter. So you would start with `//Placemark/Point/coordinates`. Then narrow it down to `Placemark`'s that have an `ExtendedData/Data/value` that is equal to `bnb`.

Comment: cool! and how can i add more criterias:  //Placemark[ExtendedData/Data/value='bnb' and @name='WayPointNumber']/Point/coordinates ??

Comment: @happymapper - Yes, but pay attention to context. `Placemark` doesn't have an attribute named `name`, but `Data` does so you'd have to put a predicate on `Data`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice - time is running out for today i will try it tomorrow.

Comment: it's getting more tricky - i need the coordinates only if 3 criterias a true. example: Data[@name='bnb'] and Data[@name='WayPointNumber'] and Data/value='numeration'. How can i add these to my xpath syntax?